# PHP: как отправить тем же запросом остаток массива, который не попадает в условие?

Tags: php, sql, массивы, csv

Уважаемые эксперты!

Читаю таблицу csv, информацию кладу в массив $temp_array, в котором она каждый раз накапливается до достижения условия  if($stop%100 == 0 || $stop == 44768). "$stop == 44768", конечно, не вариант, потому что набор данных может быть другим. А как сделать так, чтобы не попавшие в условие 68 записей таки были отправлены тем же запросом? Нужно каким-то образом отправить остаток документа, который не попадает в первое условие.. $stop%100 == 0. Буду благодарен за любой совет и помощь..

```
if (($handle = fopen( 'VED2017.csv', 'r' )) !== false) {
fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";");
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {
      $a = empty(trim($data[6])) ? 0 : 1;
      $w = empty(trim($data[7])) ? 0 : 1;
      $v = empty(trim($data[8])) ? 0 : 1;
      $g = empty(trim($data[9])) ? 0 : 1;
        $temp_array[] = "(" . 2020 . ", '$a', '$w', '$v', '$g', '" . trim($data[6]) . "', '" . trim($data[7]) . "', '" . trim($data[8]) . "', '" . trim($data[9]) . "', '" . trim($data[0]) . "', '" . trim($data[5]) . "'," . 0 . ", '" . trim($data[1]) . "')";



        if($stop%100 == 0 || $stop == 44768){
            $query =
                "INSERT INTO namebase.nametable
                (ye, sender,rec,hold,dec,send,rec,der,ecl,sys,key,stat,nn)
            VALUES " . implode(",", $temp_array);

            if ( !$b->Query( $query ) )
            {
                print("ERROR CONNECT SQL");
                exit;
            }

            $temp_array = array();

        }
$stop++;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

Comment: Проверить, что после окончания `while` в `$temp_array` есть данные и запустить запрос.

Comment: А как это сделать, я, допустим, пробовал feof($handle), но не срабатывает.. Скрипт все равно шлет только 44700, а оставшиеся 68 игнорирует

Comment: `if ($temp_array)`

Comment: И возможно ли это? цикл ведь закончится после условия по логике..

Comment: Но если сделать if ($temp_array), то это обессмыслит %100. Получится, что условие будет отправлять все.. и что делится на 100 и что не делится

Comment: Ты понимаешь, что __после__ того как `while` цикл закончится __полностью__, то у тебя в `$temp_array` будет либо сколько-то записей, либо вообще ничего не будет? Так вот когда там будет несколько записей - тебе эти записи нужно в БД вставить.

Comment: Это-то да, я понимаю, а как отразить в условии вот эту ситуацию if($stop%100 == 0 || "или остаток") - не ясно..(( Десятки вариантов перепробовал.. in_array, end() и тд..

Comment: Не подскажете, как лучше действовать? Не понимаю..

Comment: Ничего не надо отражать нигде. Просто надо __после окончания цикла__ `while` сделать еще один запрос если `$temp_array` не пуст.

Comment: Да, я тоже так сначала сделал.. но сейчас стоит задача обойтись без этого второго insertа после цикла..

Answer (score 0):

Схематично это выглядит так:

```
$temp_array = array();
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false) {
  $a = empty(trim($data[6])) ? 0 : 1;
  $w = empty(trim($data[7])) ? 0 : 1;
  $v = empty(trim($data[8])) ? 0 : 1;
  $g = empty(trim($data[9])) ? 0 : 1;
  $temp_array[] = "(" . 2020 . ", '$a', '$w', '$v', '$g', '" . trim($data[6]) . "', '" . trim($data[7]) . "', '" . trim($data[8]) . "', '" . trim($data[9]) . "', '" . trim($data[0]) . "', '" . trim($data[5]) . "'," . 0 . ", '" . trim($data[1]) . "')";

  if(100 === \count($temp_array)) {
    // делаем INSERT-запрос

    $temp_array = array();
  }
}
fclose($handle);
if ($temp_array) {
    // делаем INSERT-запрос, точно такой же что и в цикле
}
```

**Попытка два**:

```
$temp_array = array();
// Тут мы учитываем ОБА случая - и когда нам 
// вернули следующую запись и когда НЕ вернули
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) !== false || ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ";")) === false) {
    if (false !== $data) {
        $a = empty(trim($data[6])) ? 0 : 1;
        $w = empty(trim($data[7])) ? 0 : 1;
        $v = empty(trim($data[8])) ? 0 : 1;
        $g = empty(trim($data[9])) ? 0 : 1;
        $temp_array[] = "(" . 2020 . ", '$a', '$w', '$v', '$g', '" . trim($data[6]) . "', '" . trim($data[7]) . "', '" . trim($data[8]) . "', '" . trim($data[9]) . "', '" . trim($data[0]) . "', '" . trim($data[5]) . "'," . 0 . ", '" . trim($data[1]) . "')";
    }

    // набрали сто записей или следующей записи нет
    if(100 === \count($temp_array) || $data === false) {
       // делаем INSERT-запрос

        $temp_array = array();
    }
    
    // чтобы цикл не бегал вечно - делаем `break`
    if ($data === false) {
        break;
    }
}
fclose($handle);
```

Comment: Так я уже сам тоже сделал.. Но меня попросили обойтись без двух запросов.. Отправить все одним, внутри условия if

Comment: Без знания количества элементов в массиве или значения последнего элемента это невозможно.

Comment: Наверное, можно как-то.. Ведь есть разница: массив остался неполным, потому что закончились элементы или он набирается, т.е. туда могут докладываться данные до 100..

Comment: Вот как бы учесть в коде достижение конца цикла и наличие неполного массива.. но все еще внутри while..

Comment: как-то, я думаю, можно.. а как именно - непонятно

Comment: Удалил апдейт, так как он некорректен.

Comment: Добавил другой, более безумный апдейт

Comment: ух ты, отличная идея! сейчас попробую..

Comment: Но это называется экономия на спичках.

Comment: не срабатывает.. но это, наверное, из-за того, что у меня цикл while обернут в if (($handle = fopen( 'VED2017.csv', 'r' )) !== false) {             fclose($handle);}

Comment: Это вообще тут при чем?

Comment: Я взял в задание часть кода, чтобы не делать простыню, сейчас добавлю туда контекст..  Добавил..